# Prove some points are concyclic

Tags: geometry, circles, angle

**question**

We consider the triangle $ABC$ with $AB$, $AC$ and in which $(AX$, $(AY$, two half lines inside the $\angle BAC$, isogonal (ie: $\angle BAX= \angle CAY$). We consider the points $E$ and $F$ outside the triangle from which the sides $(AB)$ respectively $( AC) $are seen under the same angle, in different semi-planes determined by the line $AB$. The circumscribed circle of the triangle $ABE$ cuts the semi-steps $(AX$ respectively $(A$Y after the points $M$ and $P$, respectively the circumscribed circle of the triangle $AFC$ cuts the semi-steps $(AX$ $(AY$, after the points $N$ and $Q$.

Prove that:

a) Points $M, N, P$ and $Q$ are concyclic:

b) The centre of the circumcircle of the quadrilateral $MNPQ$ lies on the perpendicular bisector of the segment $BC$.

**my drawing**

[image]

**my idea**

$MBAP$ and $NQCA$ are inscribed quadrangles $=> \angle QAC= \angle NQA$ and $\angle BAM= \angle AMP$

We also know from the start that $\angle BAM= \angle QAC$

It means that $\angle NQA= \angle AMP=>$ what we had to prove

I dont know what to do forward. Hope one of you can help me!
Thank you!

Comment: Draw the circumcircle of ABC, suppose it intersects the perpendicular bisector of BC at G. Connect A to G. One way to show O is on perpendicular bisector of BC is to show AG is bisector of angle BAC.

Comment: @sirous i dont really understand your idea. Can you be more explicit please???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that $\angle APB = \angle CNA$ and $\angle BAP = \angle NAC$. This shows that $\triangle APB \sim \triangle ANC$. Similarly, $\angle AMB = \angle CQA$ and $\angle BAM = \angle QAC$, hence $\triangle AMB \sim \triangle AQC$.

We have $$\angle PMN = \angle PMA = \angle PBA = \angle ACN = \angle AQN = \angle PQN,$$ hence $P,Q,M,N$ are concyclic.

Let $BM$ intersect the circumcircle of $PQMN$ again at $T\neq M$. Note that $\angle PTM = \angle PQM$ and $\angle MAP = \angle MBP$, hence $\triangle BPT \sim \triangle AMQ$. Therefore $\dfrac{BT}{AQ}=\dfrac{BP}{AM}$. On the other hand, similarity $\triangle AMB \sim \triangle AQC$ gives $\dfrac{BM}{AM}=\dfrac{CQ}{AQ}$. Hence the power of $B$ with respect to the circumcircle of $PQMN$ is equal to
$$BM \cdot BT = \frac{AM\cdot CQ}{AQ} \cdot \frac{BP \cdot AQ}{AM} =  CQ \cdot BP.$$

Similarly, let $CQ$ intersect the circumcircle of $PQMN$ again at $U\neq Q$. We have $\angle APN = \angle CUN$ and $\angle NAP = \angle NCU$, hence $\triangle CUN \sim \triangle APN$ which gives $\dfrac{CU}{CN}=\dfrac{AP}{AN}$. Moreover, $\triangle APB \sim \triangle ANC$ gives $\dfrac{CN}{AN}=\dfrac{BP}{AP}$. Therefore the power of $C$ with respect to the circumcircle of $PQMN$ is equal to
$$CQ\cdot CU = CQ \cdot \frac{CN\cdot AP}{AN} = CQ \cdot \frac{\frac{BP\cdot AN}{AP}\cdot AP}{AN} = CQ \cdot BP.$$

This shows that $B$ and $C$ have equal powers with respect to the circumcircle of $PQMN$. Denote the center and the radius of this circle by $O$ and $r$. Then $BO^2-r^2=CO^2-r^2$ from which it follows that $BO=CO$. In other words, $O$ lies on the perpendicular bisector of $BC$.

Comment: Your solution seems OK but I think it should be "let $CQ$ intersects the circumcircle of $PQMN$ again at ..."

Comment: @timon92 Thank you so much for your answer! I don't understand why because $B, C$ have equal powers with respect to the circumcircle means that the circumcenter lies perpendicular bisector of BC

Comment: @RezaRajaei thanks, I fixed it.

Comment: @IONELABUCIU I added some explanation. Hopefully it is clear now.

Comment: @timon92 That's great now! [+1]